# Adding history support to ASP.NET / jquery web page

Tags: jquery, ajax, navigation

I've implemented a web page that loads content dynamically from the server via the [jQuery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin (for form POST requests) and via the standard jQuery load method (for all other requests).

Now I'd like to add history support, to properly support the back / forward browser buttons. I've managed to do this for simple links, but I always had detail problems when trying to add history support to the jquery.form POST requests. So far I have tried jquery.history and jquery.ajaxify with no luck.

Does anyone know a tutorial or have some sample code how to add history support to jquery.form ajaxed forms?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in support for modifying history directly with JQuery.  But there is a JQuery History plugin (or two or three).

http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you don't really seem to have read my question.

Comment: No, I did read it.  That was just the best I could come up with.  History support via JavaScript is just difficult.